# How do I detect if a property of type int is valid if the user deletes the value

Tags: wpf

How do I detect if a property of type int is valid if the user deletes the value.

My application has a `textbox` and a `button`. If the value in the `textbox` is valid, the `button` is shown, if not, the `button` is invisible. In the constructor, the `button` is set to invisible.

I'm using binding and my property is

```
    private int _myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set 
        {
            //various logic about if the value parses validation (if else statements), if it fails the value is set back to 0, the visibility of the button is made invisible and the code returns at this point 

            this._myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            this.MyVis = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;// it'valid
        }
    }
```

Now, if I type in something like "12A", the code inside the setter will simply detect it's not a valid string, set this._myProperty = 0 and then return (which is fine for my needs!)

The problem I have is, deleting! I am allowed to delete the content of the `textbox` but when I do, the code doesn't hit setter! Therefore the logic inside the property is never hit and my `button's visibility remains untouched (So it could remain visible). And when I click the`button`it shows the value 0 where as 0 is not what the user has entered (the textbox is null). I'd rather show my invalid numbers as -99 or null (using`int?`but even changing my properties to type`int?` does not affect this behaviour)

I'm now beginning to think using integer with textboxes is a bad thing in WPF but, it's not realistic to show my integers as strings and do various casting etc (although I guess it would fix it, I don't consider this a real fix)

Not only that but my range goes from 0 to a very large number and as such, a `combobox` or a dial is not a suitable solution to the UX.

If I change `MyProperty` to type string, the setter value *is* set when I hit delete! But as it's a number I'd like to keep the property as type `int`.  I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: This is a typical case for Commands. You should have your logic in the command function and the verification in the command's CanExecute function.

Comment: If your edit's value  is bound to MyProperty, then there is no reason the setter of the property would not be called when deleting the value inside the edit is set to an empty string. I can only assume that your setter code (one which you have not shown) discards this somehow.

Comment: @o_weisman to be honest, the logic bit doesn't exist. That setter is never hit :S But as I mention, if I change the type of that property to a string, then it does!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case for Commands.

Your XAML should look like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeNumberTextBlock"/>
<Button Command="{Binding CmdToDoSomething, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SomeNumberTextBlock, Path=Text, , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Your ViewModel:

```
#region command ToDoSomething
private DelegateCommand _cmdToDoSomething;

public DelegateCommand CmdToDoSomething {
    get { return _cmdToDoSomething ?? (_cmdToDoSomething = new DelegateCommand(ToDoSomething, CanToDoSomething)); }
}

private void ToDoSomething(Object parameter) {
    //button logic
}

private bool CanToDoSomething(Object parameter) {
    int dummyInt;
    return int.TryParse((String)parameter, out dummyInt);
}
#endregion
```

This will disable the Button when the input is not right.

If you really want to hide it:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CmdToDoSomething, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SomeNumberTextBlock, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

NB: I'm using DelegateCommand (you can found it [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html)) but any type of Command will do.

Comment: No, the ICommand is the DelegateCommand named _cmdToDoSomething

Comment: Does this logic only work if I only want to validate 1 control ?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I don't understand what you mean, please rephrase it

Comment: In this example, the button will validate the textbox. What if I had multiple textboxes and therefore multiple Property values. I assume the command is not limited to just the validation of a single value?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I never tried it but you can use a multibinding as CommandParameter and get a enumerable of string as parameter of the command, you can then validate any number of elements with the Command. I'm on my phone I'll try that later today but it should work

Comment: The only way I can get this to fire is if The TextBox is binding to a property which then calls `cmdToDoSomething.CanExecute(value)` but this means this property has to be of type String again? :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105896/discussion-between-nkoniishvt-and-mydaftquestions).

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is create private field with type int and public property with type string. In setter you can convert string to int - and will know if your input string is not correct.
Another just prevent input incorrect character.

```
private int? _myProperty = null; 
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty==null ? "" : _myProperty.ToString(); }
    set 
    {           
        int number = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value, out number))
           _myProperty = number;
        else
        {
           // you can generate exception and
           // use ExceptionValidationRule in Binding.ValidationRules 
           // in such case WPF will show red border around your textBox
           _myProperty = null;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");

        // If you use MVVM than more properly will create converter 
        // {Binding MyProperty, Converter=StringToIsEnabledConverter}
        // instead of dirrectly set visibility
        this.MyVis = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;// it'valid
    }
}
```